# JPA ManToMany association and insert, retrieve data with Spring Data Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I need to setup many to many relationship between 2 entities, namely Project and Articles.
The use case is a project that can be linked to many articles which are related. So does each article will be linked to various projects.
I am using Spring data repository in my project and having trouble persisting and retrieving this relationship with the project and articles.

```
@Entity @Table(name = "projects")
@Getter @Setter
public class Project {
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_articles",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Project addArticle(Article p) {
        if (articles == null) articles = new ArrayList<>();
        p.getProjects().add(this);
        articles.add(p);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Article entity

```
@Entity @Table(name = "articles")
@Getter @Setter
public class Article {

    @Id
    String id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String body;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_articles")
    List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

ProjectArticles join table entity. I have created it to resolve table creation issue in hibernate.

```
@Entity(name = "ProjectArticles")
@Table(name = "project_articles")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "key.project", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "key.article", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id")) }
)
@Getter @Setter
public class ProjectArticles {
    @EmbeddedId ProjectArticleId key;

    @Embeddable @Getter @Setter
    public static class ProjectArticleId {
        @Column(name = "project_id", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
        ProjectEntity project;

        @Column(name = "article_id", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
        Article article;
    }
}
```

Here are the spring data repositories.

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, String> {
    public Project findProjectByName(String name);
    public List<Project> findProjectByArticle(String articleId);
}

public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, String> {
    public List<Article> findArticlesByTitle(String title);

    // NOTE: Does not work
    @Query("SELECT a from Article a JOIN FETCH a.projects LEFT JOIN ProjectEntity p ON p.id = :project")
    public List<Article> findArticlesByProject(@Param("project") String project);

    @Query("SELECT a from Article a LEFT JOIN ProjectEntity p ON p.id = :project")
    public List<Article> findArticleByProject(ProjectEntity project);
}
```

Ideally, I want to use repo in service like below.

```
Article ar1 = articleRepository.save(new Article("Article title", "Author 1"));
Article ar2 = articleRepository.save(new Article("Article title 2", "Author 2"));
Article ar3 = articleRepository.save(new Article("Article title 3", "Author 3"));

Project pr1 = projectRepository.save(new Project("Project name 1"));
Project pr2 = projectRepository.save(new Project("Project name 2"));
Project pr3 = projectRepository.save(new Project("Project name 3"));

pr1.addArticle(ar1);
pr1.addArticle(ar2);
pr2.addArticle(ar1);
pr2.addArticle(ar2);

ar3.addProject(pr3);
ar3.addProject(pr1);
ar3.addProject(pr2);

articleRepository.findArticlesByProject("project-2-id");
projectRepository.findProjectByArticle("article-3-id");
```

But things do not work. When I add an existing article to a project and save (update) it, in the relation table ("project_articles") new row tries to enter but without a project id and I get an exception.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible the way I designed the entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of `CascadeType.PERSIST` (involved in `CascadeType.ALL` you use) is to create entity instances, set necessary two-side relations (**Project -> Articles**, **Article -> Projects**) and only then save to a database. If you save all projects then articles are saved implicitly due to `CascadeType.PERSIST` and entity relations

Try this

```
@Transactional
public void save() {
    Article ar1 = new Article("Article title", "Author 1");
    Article ar2 = new Article("Article title 2", "Author 2");
    Article ar3 = new Article("Article title 3", "Author 3");

    Project pr1 = new Project("Project name 1");
    Project pr2 = new Project("Project name 2");
    Project pr3 = new Project("Project name 3");

    pr1.addArticle(ar1);
    pr1.addArticle(ar2);
    pr1.addArticle(ar3);

    pr2.addArticle(ar1);
    pr2.addArticle(ar2);
    pr2.addArticle(ar3);

    pr3.addArticle(ar3);

    projectRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(pr1, pr2, pr3));
}
```

Comment: check my answer. I think I understand what you wanted to say but your solution was incomplete.
Thanks for responding.

Comment: I have added an explanation to the answer

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the scenario by following guidelines described in few blog posts.

- [Introduction to Spring Data JPA Part 8: Many-to-Many Bidirectional](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-spring-data-jpa-part-8-many-to-man)
- [JPA / Hibernate Many to Many Mapping Example with Spring Boot](https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-mapping-example/)

Additionally, I needed to solve JSON serialization inifinite recursion problem.

Here is the final JPA models.

```
@Entity @Table(name = "projects")
@Getter @Setter
public class Project {
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("projects")
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE, DETACH, REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_articles",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();

    public Project addArticle(Article art) {
        articles.add(art);
        art.getProjects().add(this);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Updated Article entity.

```
@Entity @Table(name = "articles")
@Getter @Setter
public class Article {

    @Id
    String id;
    String title;
    String author;
    String body;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("articles")
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles", cascade = { PERSIST, MERGE, DETACH, REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

    public Article addProject(Project prj) {
        projects.add(prj);
        prj.getArticles().add(this);
        return this;
    }    
}
```

Solved the entity save / update.

```
Article ar1 = articleRepository.save(new Article("Article title", "Author 1"));
Article ar2 = articleRepository.save(new Article("Article title 2", "Author 2"));
Article ar3 = articleRepository.save(new Article("Article title 3", "Author 3"));

Project pr1 = projectRepository.save(new Project("Project name 1"));
Project pr2 = projectRepository.save(new Project("Project name 2"));
Project pr3 = projectRepository.save(new Project("Project name 3"));

/* Link articles 1 and 3 to project 1 */
pr1.getArticles().add(ar1);
pr1.getArticles().add(ar3);
ar1.getProjects().add(pr1);
ar3.getProjects().add(pr1);

/* Link articles 2 and 3 to project 2 */
pr2.addArticle(ar3);
pr2.addArticle(ar2);

/* Link project 3 to article 3 */
ar3.addProject(pr3);
```

But yet to solve data fetching. e.g. Get all project linked to a project. (**TODO**)